# How could use Localization for jquery datepicker to become Persian ['Fr']?

Tags: jquery, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I Download Jquery datepicker from http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ and use it,know I want to my calndar's regional become 'Fr',when I use this code,nothing happend :

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```

where is my mistake? How could i localize the regional of datepicker jquery calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to know that **FR**  is not the regional setting for **Persian**, it is actually **FRENCH**, For Persian you have to set your local setting to **fa**

Then, consider that hiterto, Persian localization only changethe text and date format of the datepicker. You have to wait for complete calendar, because Persian Calendar uses a totaly different type of calendar that current **Georgian calendar**.

so use

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fa']);
```

and wait for upcoming updates

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are missing the file that contains the localization texts. I will provide it within the edit.

EDIT:

> http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/js_that_uses_datapicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: thanks @Bogdan,but I use that,also use theses:

jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css,
jquery-1.7.1.min.js,
jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js,jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js

and the code is this:


             $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
            $(function() {
                $("#date").datepicker();
            });

Comment: The order seems ok. so it should work, are you sure it isn't showing any error in firebug/developer tools?

Comment: No error on firebug,calendar open correct but it is not persian regional!!it is Also English.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
 $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {clearText: 'Effacer', clearStatus: '',
    closeText: 'Fermer', closeStatus: 'Fermer sans modifier',
    prevText: '<Préc', prevStatus: 'Voir le mois précédent',
    nextText: 'Suiv>', nextStatus: 'Voir le mois suivant',
    currentText: 'Courant', currentStatus: 'Voir le mois courant',
    monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
    'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fév','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
    'Jul','Aoû','Sep','Oct','Nov','Déc'],
    monthStatus: 'Voir un autre mois', yearStatus: 'Voir un autre année',
    weekHeader: 'Sm', weekStatus: '',
    dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa'],
    dayStatus: 'Utiliser DD comme premier jour de la semaine', dateStatus: 'Choisir le DD, MM d',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', firstDay: 0, 
    initStatus: 'Choisir la date', isRTL: false};
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```